# Why do we need to apply google-services plugin AT THE BOTTOM for Firebase SDK?

Tags: android, gradle, firebase

**EDITED**

**As [@doug-stevenson tells us in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38018985/5449688), the Firebase dependency declaration does not have to be at the bottom of build.gradle anymore.**

---

On the [Firebase SDK setup page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup), it says,

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    // ...
}

dependencies {
  // ...
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Why is that? Does the ordering matter?

Comment: I can assume that, but could you possibly explain how and why?

Comment: Note that with the latest version of the plugin, it's no longer necessary to apply it at the bottom.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**UPDATE**: With the latest version of the play services plugin, it is no longer necessary to apply it at the bottom of build.gradle.

---

It has to do with the way the plugin helps to manage dependencies, and the order of events that Gradle uses to build the project.

The plugin will actually add a dependency on firebase-core if it's not present in your project. It will also check the version of Firebase and Play Services dependencies. However, in order for it to do all this without conflict with other plugins, the Google Services plugin has to run against a project **after** the project dependencies are already defined. So, applying the plugin after the dependencies block (typically at the bottom of the file) makes all this possible.

The important thing to know is that some projects may experience a version conflict problem if the plugin is at the top. You will avoid these problems by adding it to the bottom.

Comment: I see! Thank you @doug-stevenson . Could I ask one more question? While the google-services plugin checks app's dependencies, what kind of other plugins you can think of that may cause conflict?

Comment: Any plugin that registers listeners on certain parts of the build, including the android plugin.  There cannot be any uncertainty that order these listeners will be called, so applying at the end removes this uncertainty.

Comment: What if it is already at the bottom and keeps giving the warning? I'm just creating an instant version of my game and I started getting this error after applying the com.android.feature and com.android.instantapp plugins, both at the top of the file despite keeping the com.google.gms.google-services at the bottom.

Comment: @FranMarzoa Why don't you ask a separate question and explain in more detail what you're trying to do, showing your build.gradle in the question?

Comment: I simply thought my problem wasn't worth for it. Thanks for the suggestion, though. I'll try to do some more research to see if I'm able to resolve it by myself, otherwise I'll reconsider opening a question. Thanks again!

Comment: You shouldn't need to force plugins are applied in any order. Most of the Gradle model objects have events that you can hook into (eg when objects are added to collections or before configurations are resolved). In this instance I think you can use `configurations.xxx.incoming.beforeResolve { deps -> doStuff(deps) }`

Comment: what about other plugins that use `google-services` plugin such as `io.fabric` where they should be top, bottom, below or above `google-services`?