# Gradle: "apply plugin" at the top or at the bottom

Tags: android, gradle, plugins, apply

Has the same effect add the "apply plugin" at the beginning or end of the file build.gradle in Android Studio projects?

For example to add the 'com.google.gms.google-services' plugin, Firebase official documentation recommends adding at the end, but I've seen other codes add it at the beginning.

I know the question seems irrelevant, but I'm developing a plugin for Android Studio to manage dependencies and have this doubt.

[image: Apply Plugin botton or top]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you link to the firebase documentation that advises this?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Gradle scripts are interpreted top to bottom so order can be important. Keep in mind that gradle has a configuration phase and an execution phase so sometimes order isn't important. It's common to apply your plugins at the top of the script since plugins often add [extension objects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:getting_input_from_the_build) and tasks to the gradle model which can then be configured lower down in the build script.

For example, you ***can't*** do the following because the `test` task is added by the `java` plugin:

```
test {
   include 'org/foo/**'
}
apply plugin: 'java'
```

Comment: That explains why some plugins may have to be added at/near the top. But doesn't really explain why firebase recommends adding google-services at the bottom.

Comment: If a plugin were to use `tasks.withType(...)` or similar then this may need to be applied at the bottom (or it would return nothing). To avoid this, a plugin should do these types of actions inside a `project.afterEvaluate { ... }` block. Perhaps the plugin doesn't do this so order is important?

Comment: Doug Stevenson from the Firebase team explained in an answer why the google-services plugin must be placed at the bottom: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37994514/why-do-we-need-to-apply-google-services-plugin-at-the-bottom-for-firebase-sdk

Comment: I added a comment to that issue, if they changed the implementation to add an eventlistener to the configuration then they could intercept the configuration just before it is resolved. If they did this then you could declare the plugin at the top of the Gradle script